# Как проверить является ли одно из слов частью другого

Tags: java

Нужно проверить, является ли одно из слов частью другого. Например, "Рыба" и "Рыбаки", а также "1Рыба" и "Рыба" считаются совпадениями.

Пробую делать так:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> wordToCount = new HashMap<>();
for (String root : words) {
    if (!wordToCount.containsKey(root)) {
        wordToCount.put(root, 0);
    }
    wordToCount.put(root, wordToCount.get(root) + 1);
}
```

Но так получается найти только идентичные слова: "Рыба" и "Рыба", "Рыбак" и "Рыбак".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение "в лоб" - брать все пары строк и проверять, содержится ли в более длинной строке более короткая.

Реализовать его можно примерно так:

```
String[] words = new String[] { "Рыба", "Рыбаки", "1Рыба", "Два Гладиолуса", "Гладиолус" };
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++)
    {
        if (words[i].length() < words[j].length())
        {
            if (words[j].contains(words[i]))
            {
                System.out.println(words[j] + " содержит " + words[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (words[i].contains(words[j]))
            {
                System.out.println(words[i] + " содержит " + words[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод на экран:

> Рыбаки содержит Рыба
>   1Рыба содержит Рыба
>   Два Гладиолуса содержит Гладиолус

---

В некоторых ситуациях оптимальнее будет построение дерева (ДКА) по всем словам.